# How can I remove the interior side of a Kwikset handle set with "interconnect"?

Tags: doors, lock, deadbolt

I just moved into this house that came with a handle set that includes some kind of interconnect plate on the inside that serves to unlock the deadbolt when the knob is turned.  I want to remove the entire interior side to put an August smartlock retrofit thing on the deadbolt part and install a regular door knob on the interior of the latch.

Here's what I'm working with:
[image: Interior of handle set]

[image: Side view of handle set]

The deadbolt and latch are not connected except by a strange plate assembly behind that face plate surrounding the interior knobs.  I can remove the screws of that face plate and pull it out at the top enough to rotate it about the lower knob, but can't seem to find any screws that hold that plate onto the door.  The lower knob doesn't seem to have any little screws for removing it either.  Is there a trick to removing the lower knob?  If I could do that, I would be able to see the entire interconnect plate, and I think I could figure out how to remove it from there.

[image: faceplate removed]

Here you can see the interconnect plate.

[image: behind the doorknob]

Comment: I have the exact same problem removing this door handle. Were you able to figure out how to remove the knob?

Comment: I have undeleted my post which describes what I actually had to do.  It was down-voted simply because the answer is that you have to destroy the thing and someone was not happy with that.  Best of luck to you.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for undeleting it.  Sorry, you had to destroy it. However, I figured out the right way and posted the answer below. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: That’s great, Eswar!  I’m glad to see there is a way to remove it.  I’ve changed the accepted answer to yours.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone still needs help with this, i finally figured out the right way to remove this type of interconnected lock set. Thanks to Locksmith Ben, who was kind enough to help me on face time :)

There is a tiny square shaped pin, which was spring loaded. i had to push it upwards and pull the knob out.

Here is an annotated picture of my lock

[image: here is an annotated picture of my lock]

Here is the OP picture I annotated.

[image]

Comment: Dear Eswar and Eric, Thank you for your information! Unfortunately, the place Eswar pointed in the second picture was not the right spot. It is actually hidden behind the plate and you need to use a small screw driver to push it up. Here is the picture after I removed the plate so that it is clear to see where to poke https://photos.app.goo.gl/sy5DZMYxgnBsTb4QA

Answer (score 2):

The inside knobs are often removed on this type of product via a small slot or hole that will be visible at the stem of the knob. For a slot insert a small flat blade screwdriver in the slot and press in whilst pulling the knob away from the door.

If there is just a small hole insert a round pin or small sized allen wrench in the hole. Press in the pin and apply pulling pressure on the knob to remove.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no slot and no small hole.  I'll post more photos to clarify if I can.

Comment: There may very well be some type of removable C-clip or spring loaded catch in a slot or hole that reveals itself when you look behind that larger trim plate. (Maybe that copper colored thing in your most recent picture)? Rather inconvenient to disengage the knob that way but then there are often less than user friendly designs proffered to the public.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm in the thick of it now... probably breaking stuff as I go, so no turning back!  I did find a clip that went around the knob mechanism close to the interconnect plate. I popped it out of position along with some o-ring that it was holding in place.  The knob seems no looser yet, however.